# uglify is not working using gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

I have a basic script like so

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('default',function(){
    return gulp.src('homeScreen/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Where I am trying to uglify the js code. But for whatever reason,it is not happening. It comes in the single line but it is still readable.

I have install gulp,uglify like this

```
npm install gulp --save
npm install gulp-uglify --save
```

Can someone say what is wrong?

Output

--Pre

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".coins").animate({ "left": "00px" }, "slow" );
  $(".volumnControls").animate({ "left": "00px" }, "slow" );

  $('#volumnOff').hide();

    $('#volumnOn,#volumnOff').click(function(){
      $('#volumnOn,#volumnOff').toggle();
      playAndPause();
    });



    $('#store').click(function(){
      window.location = '../shop/shopHome.html';
    });


    $('#howToPlay,.close').click(function()
    {
         $('#myModal').toggleClass('modalAppear modalDisAppear'); //Adds 'a', removes 'b' and vice versa
         $('.close').css('display','none'); //Adds 'a', removes 'b' and vice versa
    });

    $('.next-controls').click(function(){
      $('.close').css('display','inline-block'); //Adds 'a', removes 'b' and vice versa
      $('.next-controls').css('display','none'); //Adds 'a', removes 'b' and vice versa
      $('.slide-text').css('display','none');
    });

    $('.close').click(function(){
      $('.next-controls').css('display','inline-block'); //Adds 'a', removes 'b' and vice versa
        $('.slide-text').css('display','inline-block');
    });

});
```

--Post

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(".coins").animate({left:"00px"},"slow"),$(".volumnControls").animate({left:"00px"},"slow"),$("#volumnOff").hide(),$("#volumnOn,#volumnOff").click(function(){$("#volumnOn,#volumnOff").toggle(),playAndPause()}),$("#store").click(function(){window.location="../shop/shopHome.html"}),$("#howToPlay,.close").click(function(){$("#myModal").toggleClass("modalAppear modalDisAppear"),$(".close").css("display","none")}),$(".next-controls").click(function(){$(".close").css("display","inline-block"),$(".next-controls").css("display","none"),$(".slide-text").css("display","none")})
```

Comment: Can you post a few lines pre-uglify and post-uglify?

Comment: please check the outputs @Intervalia

Comment: Looks like it did what it was supposed to. You don't have any variables or anything that _can_ be minified. So removal of spaces is all it can do.

Comment: but when i run this on browser and click the {} on console it is readable.

Comment: How to make it unreadable?

Comment: `uglify` does not make things unreadable. That is obfuscation and doing that is not worth the effort because the end user can de-obfuscate and still read your code. `uglify` removes spaces and minifies variable and function names and few other things, but it leaves the code readable.

Comment: I heared that uglify makes the code unreadable and can't be converted back.

Comment: And in my code the function name are still the same.

Comment: no. `uglify` is a minifier not an obfuscator. And I don't see any of your own function names in the example you posted.